# Plugging in USB device causes electrical sound and system freeze

Tags: usb, freeze

When I try to connect some device to my computer's USB ports, a strange sound comes (electric sound) and my PC suddenly freezes.  It doesn't happens all the time, but randomly I think.

Motherboard: Asus M5A99FX PRO R2.0

**EDIT:**

- My computer becomes completely unresponsive when this problem happens, and I then need to restart the PC.
- It happens with all devices like my mouse, keyboard, mobile phone or headset.
- It happens with all USB ports (I tried with 2-3 different ports).
- The strange sound comes from the PC itself, not the speakers.

Comment: Have you verified all header connections are secure

Comment: Is it static shock?  Try grounding yourself/the usb plug before inserting into the port.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know. I only use usb(my mouse, keyboard, headset)

Comment: @Kruug Can it be static shock? I just tried to connect my phone nearly 15 times and there was no problem.

Comment: With any of the ports? What if you connect a USB hub to a port and connect to a hub. You could try a small M-F USB extension cable. ending in a female socket and plug into that and see if you still get the problem. a bit of a workaround.

Comment: Is it a high power device?  It could be the device is pulling more power than the USB bus will safely provide.

Comment: You will have to verify the question I asked involves opening up the computer and checking I can't help unless you do this so you don't have to reply to me until you do

Comment: @hellzone yes, it could be.  Your phone charger and the USB port may not be at different static levels, resulting in no shock.  It's a fickle thing, electricity.

Comment: @trpt4him just my phone or my mouse.

Comment: Does your computer blue-screen, become completely unresponsive, or self-reset? A short in the assembly could cause the specified behavior.